# Lua, Discordia, DIscord API and Forms

Tags: lua, discord

I appreciate any help you can offer.

I am trying to create a text input feature on my bot, the discord API already has this, but I'm struggling to implement.

At the moment, I use this module to implement components for discord, as discordia doesn't support them:
https://github.com/Bilal2453/discordia-components

discord docs for text input: https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#text-inputs

(Buttons etc are working fine)
For some reason, this module doesn't have text inputs, so I found the [Component](https://github.com/Bilal2453/discordia-components/wiki/Component) class and constructor and tried to manually enter the data to be sent to discord. My code looks like this:

```lua
local RAWDATA = {
    ["title"] = "My Cool Modal",
    ["custom_id"] = "cool_modal",
    ["components"] = {
        {
            ["type"] = 1,
            ["components"] = {
                {
                    ["type"] = 4,
                    ["custom_id"] = "name",
                    ["label"] = "Name",
                    ["style"] = 1,
                    ["min_length"] = 1,
                    ["max_length"] = 4000,
                    ["placeholder"] = "John",
                    ["required"] = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
local InputComponent = discordia.Component(RAWDATA)
InputComponent:set(RAWDATA)
DM:sendComponents("this wont work", InputComponent)
```

- The console can't be more specific than the 400 error response.

Thank you in advance! Sorry for anything I may have overlooked.